# Getting Microsoft Team context in an angular app added as a tab

Tags: angular, typescript, microsoft-teams

I am adding an Angular website to a Microsoft Teams tab. I want to get the Tteam ID for doing some computation. I just installed `npm install --save @microsoft/teams-js`.

This is the code I used

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "app";
  teamID: string;
  teamName: string;
  groupID: string;
  ngOnInit() {
    microsoftTeams.initialize();

    microsoftTeams.getContext(function(Context: microsoftTeams.Context) {
      alert("getcontext call back function");
      this.teamName = Context.teamName;
      this.groupID = Context.groupId;
      this.teamID = Context.teamId;
    });

    alert("after get context");
    console.log("End");
  }
}
```

The problem here is that I'm not getting the `microsoftTeams.Context`. Is there something else I have to do? What is the proper way to approach this?

Comment: Check this sample code (https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node) for accessing team context using nodeJS.

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console or the server?

Comment: Are you sure that your page is loaded? If the function is called before the page has finished being loaded/rendered, it's not going to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

context is a callback so you need to add .bind(this) after microsoftTeams.getContext. 
Like this:

```
microsoftTeams.getContext(function(Context: microsoftTeams.Context) {
    alert("getcontext call back function");
    this.teamName = Context.teamName;
    this.groupID = Context.groupId;
    this.teamID = Context.teamId;
}).bind(this));
```